# How to find network usage in linux programatically

Tags: python, linux, network-programming, ubuntu-12.04, performance-testing

I am trying to calculate total network traffic on  `wlan1` interface through a python code. Uptil now I tried `ethtool`,`iftop`,`ifstat`,`nethogs` but most of these tools show ncurses interface(text base UI).

I tried something like this

```
import subprocess
nw_usage = subprocess.Popen(['ifstat', '-i', 'wlan1'])
```

but it doesn't give me network usage values.

I could not figure out how to get network usage values in a single variable from ncurses interfaces. ( and I am getting a feeling that there would be some better way to calculate network usage)

Any help or direction will be a great favor.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered `tshark`, the commandline version of wireshark?

Comment: Define network usage. What exactly you want to know? Traffic speed in network interfaces?

Comment: I need transmit rate on a network interface at a given time. e.g. `x=somefunction(wlan1)` should give me `x Kbps/Mbps` which I can compare with max transmission rate of that interface 
(i.e. 56Mbps connection speed)

Comment: `inspectorG4dget` I just tried tshark,but I don't need packets... I  need transmission rate

Answer (score 5):

i know that the question is some weeks old but maybe this answer can still be helpful :)

You could read the device statistics from /proc/net/dev. Read the transmitted / received bytes in a interval and calculate the difference. Here is some simple Python script i hacked together

```
import re
import time


# A regular expression which separates the interesting fields and saves them in named groups
regexp = r"""
  \s*                     # a interface line  starts with none, one or more whitespaces
  (?P<interface>\w+):\s+  # the name of the interface followed by a colon and spaces
  (?P<rx_bytes>\d+)\s+    # the number of received bytes and one or more whitespaces
  (?P<rx_packets>\d+)\s+  # the number of received packets and one or more whitespaces
  (?P<rx_errors>\d+)\s+   # the number of receive errors and one or more whitespaces
  (?P<rx_drop>\d+)\s+      # the number of dropped rx packets and ...
  (?P<rx_fifo>\d+)\s+      # rx fifo
  (?P<rx_frame>\d+)\s+     # rx frame
  (?P<rx_compr>\d+)\s+     # rx compressed
  (?P<rx_multicast>\d+)\s+ # rx multicast
  (?P<tx_bytes>\d+)\s+    # the number of transmitted bytes and one or more whitespaces
  (?P<tx_packets>\d+)\s+  # the number of transmitted packets and one or more whitespaces
  (?P<tx_errors>\d+)\s+   # the number of transmit errors and one or more whitespaces
  (?P<tx_drop>\d+)\s+      # the number of dropped tx packets and ...
  (?P<tx_fifo>\d+)\s+      # tx fifo
  (?P<tx_frame>\d+)\s+     # tx frame
  (?P<tx_compr>\d+)\s+     # tx compressed
  (?P<tx_multicast>\d+)\s* # tx multicast
"""


pattern = re.compile(regexp, re.VERBOSE)


def get_bytes(interface_name):
    '''returns tuple of (rx_bytes, tx_bytes) '''
    with open('/proc/net/dev', 'r') as f:
        a = f.readline()
        while(a):
            m = pattern.search(a)
            # the regexp matched
            # look for the needed interface and return the rx_bytes and tx_bytes
            if m:
                if m.group('interface') == interface_name:
                    return (m.group('rx_bytes'),m.group('tx_bytes'))
            a = f.readline()


while True:
    last_time  = time.time()
    last_bytes = get_bytes('wlan0')
    time.sleep(1)
    now_bytes = get_bytes('wlan0')
    print "rx: %s B/s, tx %s B/s" % (int(now_bytes[0]) - int(last_bytes[0]), int(now_bytes[1]) - int(last_bytes[1]))
```

Comment: Awesome, works fine even with Python 3. Really nice job!

Comment: Really nice job (Y)

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way, but an ugly workaround I used to estimate network rates from the command line is:

```
ifconfig; sleep 10; ifconfig;
```

Then just subtract the "TX bytes" (in case of transmission) on the relevant interface and divide by 10 (the sleep time) for a rough estimate in **B**ytes per second.

Comment: I need a bit faster results, somewhat closer to real time